# How do I get the Product ID in the filter 'woocommerce_product_get_weight'?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code in my functions.php file and does indeed change the weight for all products but I would like to isolate it to a specific product.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'rs_product_get_weight', 10, 1);
function rs_product_get_weight($weight) {
    $weight = 45.67;

    return $weight;
}
```

Is there any way to determine the product ID in my filter function?

Comment: unfortunately not with that hook (imo). do you want to override the weight inserted and save it to the database or you just need to display a different value (without touching the db) in your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid to say it doesn't work this way...
if you look at woocommerce get_weight function

```
public function get_weight() {

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', $this->weight ? $this->weight : '' );
}
```

Maybe you are referencing to and old version of woocommerce...

So, for example, if you want to change dinamically a cart product weight, you have to hook woocommerce_before_calculate_totals filter

and add this function

```
public function action_before_calculate( WC_Cart $cart ) {

        if ( sizeof( $cart->cart_contents ) > 0 ) {

            foreach ( $cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $values ) {

                $_product = $values['data'];

                {

                ////we set the weight
                $values['data']->weight = our new weight;

            }


            }
        }
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

It's a little strange, but product weight seems to come from the `get_weight()` method which has 2 filters inside of it. The one you are referencing and also `woocommerce_product_weight` which does indeed have the product ID also passed along.

```
/**
 * Returns the product's weight.
 * @todo   refactor filters in this class to naming woocommerce_product_METHOD
 * @return string
 */
public function get_weight() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_weight', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', $this->weight ? $this->weight : '' ), $this );
}
```

Therefore you should be able to filter the weight with:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_weight', 'rs_product_get_weight', 10, 2);
function rs_product_get_weight($weight, $product) {
    if( $product->id == 999 ){
        $weight = 45.67;
    }

    return $weight;
}
```